# Wordpress/Woocommerce only show category in shop to a single role

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

I need to hide the "professional" category of products from all but the wholesale customer role. Looking to add a filter to functions, not in a template.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Will you please explain briefly? You want to hide one category from shop page but for perticular role,is it?